# Magento2: Get category product count which is show in admin after the category name

Tags: magento2, category, collection, product-collection

I want to show category product count which is shown in admin **after the category name.**
As of now I write this code but it's not working properly.

```
$category->getProductCollection()->count();
```

Please see the image to get better idea.

**Magento Backend**

[image: Please see the image to get better idea.]

**Magento Frontend**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is still relevant but answering it anyway. The answer post by @Jean Paul CP is correct.  `$category->getProductCount();` return exactly the count which shown in the admin panel categories listing. On the other hand `$category->getProductCollection()->count();` only returns count of active saleable products in the category.

Answer (score 3):

To get the current category product count

Create your own module at below location **Magento_root/app/code** for that create **Package/Modulename**

Create below files there

> **registration.php**
>
> **etc/module.xml**
>
> **Block/Blockfile.php**
>
> **view/frontend/layout/module_section_page.xml**
>
> **view/frontend/templates/template.phtml**

Put this code in your **Blockfile.php**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Block;

class Blockfile extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getCurrentCategory(){
        $current_Category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        return $current_Category;
    }
}
```

& this code in your **template.phtml**

```
    <?php
    $current_Category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
echo $current_Category->getName().'('.$current_Category->getProductCollection()->Count().')';
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
if($current_Category->hasChildren()){
    $subCategories = $current_Category->getChildrenCategories($categories);
      foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
         echo '<li style="color:Green;"><a href="'.$subCategory->getUrl().'">'.$subCategory->getName().'(' .$subCategory->getProductCollection()->Count().')'.'</a></li>';
          }
}
```

Run The below Command & see the changes

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Still facing any issue feel free to revert back

**Update:**

It is working fine for me you can have a look

**Backend:**

[image]

**Frontend**

[image][image][image][image]

> Note: Try to avoid the use of **objectmanager** into the template
>   files

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code, But my requirement is not for current category product collection count.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: I want the count which is show in the category name bracket, Actually I debug the code and that count comes from the Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree.php  Function: buildNodeName($node), You can check to get more Idea.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Code working fine, But still you check my question for M20 Mixer(140) admin and still here it is M20 Mixer(20). Still debug.....

Comment: Try to reindex your products & see if the products are conflicting or present into the two categories it happens sometime due to data also because if the code is wrong then it will show wrong value for all the categories but it is working right for some & wrong for some of them it means it is the problem of product mapping not of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73559/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-ravi).

Comment: The other thing is it can be due to the visibility is off (set => Not Visible Individually)for the frontend site of the product due to that also it will show the wrong count

Comment: @Ravi Any Updates? Do you still facing any problem?

Answer (score 1):

This one using `objectmanager`. You can also inject the `CategoryFactory` and use it. As per your requirement you need to pass the category ID in `foreach` to achieve this.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cateinstance = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$allcategoryproduct = $cateinstance->create()->load($cateid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo $count = $allcategoryproduct->count();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code, But same issue still there.

Comment: What issue? Is the count wrong?

Comment: Yes, count wrong, you can see the count in my Question.

Comment: I think you have written like only for visible products. Because the remaining category counts are correct.

Comment: My all products are Catalog, Search  , So no need to make any changes there.

Comment: I hope you can able to print product Ids, debug the coming product Id's with missing product Ids in that particular category then compare those Ids to get some Idea. I think mostly this issue belongs to indexing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
$product_count = $category->getProductCount();
```

Comment: Please do not post answers with code only. Explain what the code is doing and how it will solve the OP's issue

Comment: It is not recommended to use ObjectManager directly. We should use CategoryResourceModel to query the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Category/ProductsCount.php

```
    $productsCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $productsCollection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $productsCollection = $this->stockProcessor->process($productsCollection, $this->searchCriteria, []);

    return $productsCollection->getSize();
```

Comment: This method will not count the products of child category

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test. Did you check isAnchor @huykon225?

Comment: Yes I check. I have seen the different between magento default with graphql. The graphql return without count the products of child categories

Answer (score 1):

Admin panel uses:

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection::setLoadProductCount(true)
```

This flag adds products count to categories in collection. Use the flag before load(). **It counts products of child categories too**.

For **example**, I want to get products count for categories 4 and 5:

```
$categoryCollection->setLoadProductCount(true)
    ->addIdFilter([4,5])
    ->load();
```

Also you can use next method of the collection:

```
loadProductCount($items, $countRegular = true, $countAnchor = true)
```